# FLVMETA add cuepoints to flv from xml tags file

Tags: video, metadata, flv, video-encoding

flvtool2 does this
with a simple command like so

> [flvtool2 -APUt tags.xml src.flv
>   output.flv](http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2007/03/18/flvtool2-flash-video-flv-metadata-cue-point-injector-and-cutting-tool/)
>   where tags contains the cuepoint data in a xml file.

How can this be done with flvmeta.

The problem i am facing with flvtool2 the timestamps rounding . after much failed trials to recompile the edited source in ruby. I have come across flvmeta as a tool to inject metadata onto flv.which supposedly is faster and efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, it is not possible to inject cuepoints using flvmeta, because such feature has not been implemented yet.

By the way, flvtool2, being a pure ruby tool, does not need to be compiled, it can be executed as-is if you modify the source files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. we can execute as is? could you please post a few commands on how to do this?